# What's the difference between publish and multicast operator in rxjs 5?

Tags: rxjs5

I'm reading the rxjs manual, I'm a little confused about what's the difference between multicast and publish operators. They seem very similar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same question when reading http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html. So to make it clear, `.publish()` is just shorthand for `.multicast(new Rx.Subject())` (and `publishBehavior`, `publishLast`, and `publishReplay` are similar but instantiate `BehaviorSubject`, `AsyncSubject` and `ReplaySubject` respectively).

Answer (score 5):

They are indeed very similar, and they have a history that makes it even more confusing.

In simple terms, publish is a special case of multicast. publish always creates a new subject (and then pretty much uses multicast), whereas multicast uses the subject provided as an argument.